# What happens in Android if an SQLite query returns a result too large for memory?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm not sure what the memory limitations on Android applications are exactly, but let's say I run a query against SQLite and the result set is very large; too large to fit in whatever memory is allocated for my application. Will the application crash? I wonder if there's some trickiness that goes on in the Cursor class, with it maybe not retrieving all results at once? I don't really understand how Cursor works underneath.

Comment: I don't know about sqlite on android, but working with databases in general, the assumption is when you fetch a limited number of rows. Only those rows reside in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side effects of large memory consumption.

It may give [OutOfMemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) while reading data.

Because of too large memory consumption, it will increase CPU usage because of which *battery* will *start draining out* and if it goes beyond some limit (which I don't know) then Android system may *kill your process* or your application also might get *crashed*.